# Selfexectued function not working

Tags: javascript

Why isn't this working?

```
function init() {
    // var x = ...
    // some more code ..
}();
```

Throws: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

And why does this work fine?

```
function init() {
    // var x = ...
    // some more code ..
}(init)();
```

I just want a function, that has its own declared vars inside, but I don't want that function to be accessible any more. The last one does what I say, but why is that working? Neither I could get to know how did I came up to that solution.

Comment: https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20self%20executing%20function

Comment: Is this something you're testing in the console?

Comment: @ckersch Yes I am, would it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't this working?

You're trying to immediately invoke a *function declaration* (`function` as a statement) not a *function expression* (`function` as an operator). You'll need to do something to make the interpreter read it as an expression.

---

> And why does this work fine?

Whitespace means little in *JavaScript*, so

```
function foo() {
}(foo)();
```

Is the same as

```
function foo() {
}
(foo)();
```

Is the same as

```
function foo() {
}
foo();
```

i.e. you're just invoking it like a normal declared function

---

Best practice for writing a *named IIFE* is

```
(function foo() {
    // foo's body
}());
```

For an *anonymous IIFE*, just drop the name and keep the rest the same

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it was like this:

```
(function init() {
   console.log(3)
})();
```

Your second example is the same as this if you replace init with the function code

Answer (score 1):

```
function init(){}
```

returns `undefined`.

```
(function init(){})
```

returns a function.

Since function definition doesn't return the function, you can't call the function by adding the parens `()` at the end. For defining and calling a function, you should use this pattern instead:

```
(function init(){})();
```

Or just use an anonymous function if you don't need to call `init` again:

```
(function(){})();
```